# System program problem detected in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wine, system

I have some issue on my ubuntu 18.04. The message that I have get is like this: [System program problem detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mefl4.png). Probably it caused after I download wine and it's having some error on the progress.

It's probably because i update wine and it having some error. When I update, it looks like this:
[sudo apt update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4P49D.png)

What should i do to resolve this?

Comment: What about "Report problem ..." ? Going through that procedure, you will create a error report to the developers, and then someone might fix your problem at some point.

Comment: Muhammad, are you able to ping the ip address that is timing out? Also, you might be able to get more clues by typing `dmesg | less` and looking for errors and warnings there.